# using android studio to create project,but append error

Tags: android

this is error msg:
Failed to import Gradle project: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':StudioTest'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':StudioTest'.
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':StudioTest:_DebugCompile'.
Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+.
Required by:
    StudioTestProject:StudioTest:unspecified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, after updating to Android Studio 0.2.x and creating or opening a project, you receive an error stating "Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+", then you must install the Android Support Repository. This was likely caused because you're pointing Android Studio to an external Android SDK location that does not have the new Maven repository included with Android Studio 0.2.x. This new Maven repository is used by the new build system for the Support Library, instead of using the Support Library JAR files, so must be present in the SDK.

Open the Android SDK Manager.
Expand the Extras directory and install Android Support Repository.
If you've encountered other problems in Android Studio, look at the following page for possible resolutions to known issues: http://tools.android.com/knownissues.